# Keyframing angular velocity (linear acceleration of orbiting bodies)

Tags: animation, keyframes, graph-editor

I am creating the visuals for a collaborative ambisonics project, and have run into an issue.

An orbiting body has initial frequency of 0.5Hz at 0s, accelerates linearly up to 8Hz at the 30s mark and further accelerates up to 16Hz at 50s.

Is there any way to keyframe angular velocity in Blender? I am truly stumped.

Many thanks in advance,

Franky

Comment: Is the frame rate you use 24/sec?

Comment: Using 60fps due to the speed of the orbit

Answer (score 2):

The angular frequency is the gradient of the curve in the Graph Editor View. For example

$$
\frac{43200-14400}{1801-1201}=48.0 \ \  [deg/frame] \ \ \   at \  1801 frame \ .
$$

[image]